# How to align QPushButton and QComboBox in a horizontal layout?

Tags: c++, qt5

I am trying to align `QPushButton` and `QComboBox` in a horizontal layout, but for some reason I cannot do it and I always get this kind of alignment:

[image]

So, `QComboBox` is always a bit higher than it should be.

This is on macOS Big Sur 11.2.3 and version of Qt is 5.12.10. Is there some kind of workaround or fix for this?

Comment: @drescherjm No, font sizes and font are the same. They are newly created widgets, with default settings, nothing is changed, except default text in `QPushButton` which is Unicode circle in this case. Same happens if I put `QLineEdit` near `QPushButton`. As if `QPushButton` is drawn little lower or vice versa, it is drawn normally but other elements are drawn higher.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the layout stretch of the items to the same value.
[image: In the Designer]

or with code:
`horizontalLayout->setStretch(1 /* Item index */, 1 /* Stretch Factor */) // Do that for all items.`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#setStretch

Comment: Nah, it didn't help. I have found a workaround, I will post it soon as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround. I found [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/87291/qcombobox-and-qpushbutton-in-a-grid-layout-do-not-line-up-properly-in-macos) topic on Qt Forum and it seems that for some reason `QPushButton` is drawn that way. So for now I have overridden method `paintEvent()` which now draws button on more or less good position:

```
virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override {
    QStylePainter p(this);
    QStyleOptionButton option;
    initStyleOption(&option);
    option.rect = rect().adjusted(0, -2, 0, -2);
    p.drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, option);
}
```